# 500 Internal Server Error for rails app with no errors recorded in any log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application that is giving a 500 Internal Server Error page when I try and visit it (it's at http://www.helendan.rtwilson.com), however I can't find any details on the error in any of the log files.

I've tried looking inside `./log` in the rails application directory and there is nothing in any of the log files there. I've also tried looking at the web server logs themselves, and the `access.log` file shows an access to `/` and a request for the favicon, but nothing else, and the `error.log` is completely blank.

I have run `rails console` and checked that I can do some basic things with my application. For example:

```
>> rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
irb(main):001:0> @p = Present.find(1)
=> #<Present id: 1, title: "Nice Sheets", notes: "We'd like some nice sheets for our married bed. Pre...", est_price: "50", taken: true, created_at: "2011-01-29 23:56:17", updated_at: "2011-05-05 10:46:58">
irb(main):002:0> exit
```

and that all seems to work fine.

I'm at a loss as to where to look to find out what on earth the error is, and therefore how to debug it. As far as I'm aware the application worked fine last time I used it!

Any ideas on where I might be able to find some sort of error message? (This is on a shared server at Dreamhost by the way, so I am limited in certain things I can do).

**Update:** I have now been shown the error message by Dreamhost support, and it is as follows:

```
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources

Try running `bundle install`.

*** Exception EOFError in spawn manager (Unexpected end-of-file
detected.) (process 22025):

    from /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:306:in
`unmarshal_and_raise_errors'

    from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:71:in
`spawn_application'

    from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:41:in
`spawn_application'

    from /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:159:in
`spawn_application'

    from /dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in
`handle_spawn_application'

    from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'

    from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'

    from
/dh/passenger/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in
`start_synchronously'

    from /dh/passenger/bin/passenger-spawn-server:61

[ pid=21527 file=ext/apache2/Hooks.cpp:727 time=2012-01-09 16:12:58.339
]:

 Unexpected error in mod_passenger: Cannot spawn application
'/home/robintw/rails/presents-hd': The spawn server has exited
unexpectedly.

 Backtrace:

    in 'virtual boost::shared_ptr
Passenger::ApplicationPoolServer::Client::get(const
Passenger::PoolOptions&)' (ApplicationPoolServer.h:471)
```

They're saying that it's a problem with my apps configuration, but I'm not so sure. Running `rails server` works fine from the command line - and I can access the application via `lynx` on `localhost:3000` and it works fine. I've run `bundle install` and it doesn't find anything it needs to install, and says that `rake-0.9.2.2` is installed already.

Any ideas on what I might be able to do about this?

Comment: It could be your Rails app is configured to save logs in another directory.

Comment: Thanks @BehrangSaeedzadeh, I've checked all of the config files and can't find a setting for a specific log directory. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue, and I see there isn't an answer yet. I also see that the website you were having issues with is now up and running. Can you please post the answer to this?

Comment: @gdavis: Unfortunately I never found out what fixed it. I basically recreated the app from scratch, writing all of the code from scratch (with a bit of copying and pasting) and it seemed to work... Sorry I can't be more help!

Answer (score 1):

If there was a problem with the logfile, you'd see an error starting `rails console`. My guess is it's a web server configuration error, in which case you'll need to take a look at the web server logs. I'm not sure, but hopefully they're accessible from somewhere in your home directory.

Comment: Just noticed you're loading development environment in `rails console`. Is that locally or on your Dreamhost account?

Comment: I'm running rails console on my Dreamhost account, and I've also tried loading the production environment (`rails console production`) and it still works as it does above. I've looked at the web server logs, but there is absolutely nothing coming up in `error.log`. Accesses are shown in `access.log` so I know I'm in the right directory.

Comment: I've emailed Dreamhost support about this, according to http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Rails_troubleshooting they can access the 'global apache error log' which may have some useful info.

Comment: I've managed to get access to the logs - and wondered if you had any other ideas now you're able to see them?

Comment: Try this: On your local system, run `bundle package` from your rails root. This will store the gems source files in `vendor/cache`. Next, ensure your `deploy.rb` contains `require 'bundler/capistrano'`. Push these changes to git then `cap deploy`. If it works as expected, bundler will install the required gems from `vendor/cache`. If that fails, perhaps you need to make your app's rake version match the system's, in which case `gem search rake` from a shell to see what's available then update your `Gemfile` to match the latest available version and run `bundle update rake`. Push and deploy.